# Python using wrong version on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, sublimetext

I'm new to Python, I'm using version 3.8.2 on Sublime Text and Mac.

I aliased the python version from 2.7 to 3 on the command terminal and it works fine whenever I check for the version on the terminal window. However, when I run some code on Sublime Test and check for the path used, it uses the 2.7 version.

I tried to run the script using the terminal window but it couldn't find the script because of system path issues. I'm now sure how to edit or where to change that.

I tried editing the Sublime Build settings with the below but it didn't work and I'm not sure if this is how to fix it.

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "quiet": true
}
```

My script is located in the User > Documents > Python folder. Python is installed in Mac's Application folder.

Attached is a sample of my code after running it and the terminal after running it.

[Cmd Terminal - running my_module.py script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3sOQ.png)

[Sublime Text - running courses.py and checking system path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBQgM.png)

Comment: Please add errors and code _as text_ instead of links. See [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: take a look at this https://gist.github.com/zaemiel/4fbd8b5125fda7a140be

Comment: How did you install python on your Mac?  Do you recall?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your location where python is. Python 3 is not on your bin.

Go to Tools > Build System > New Build System and paste this in and save it as Python3.sublime-build

```
{
 "cmd": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
 "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
 "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Then go back and change your build system to the new Python3.

Tools > Build System > Python3

The run this test script with Command B

```py
thing = 'world'
print(f'hello {thing}')
```

and if it runs correctly, then it is running python 3.

Comment: just for my amusement. Try running `which python3` in your command line.

Comment: Seems like its running the 3.8 just fine but not when i run the script...
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3

Comment: That's what I thought. This snippet does work on my mac with sublime. I'm going to edit my answer to add some set up instructions.

Comment: Just to be clear, after making the changes you mentioned, I can't build the script on Sublime anymore. But when I use Tools > Build System > Python (instead of Python3), the build works